# Minimal number of vertices in a graph with special Hadwiger partitions

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, undirected graph.

We call a partition ${\cal P}$ of a non-empty subset of $V$ a *Hadwiger partition* if

1. every block (member of ${\cal P}$) is non-empty and connected, and
2. if $x, y \in {\cal P}$ are distinct blocks then there are $v\in x$ and $w \in y$ such that $\{v,w\} \in E$.

The *Hadwiger number* $\eta(G)$ is the maximum number of blocks a Hadwiger partition can have.

Let $n=\eta(G)$ and suppose that

1. every Hadwiger partition of $G$ into $n$ blocks contains at least one block consisting of 1 vertex only ("singleton block"), and
2. for all $v\in V$ we have $\eta(G\setminus\{v\}) = n$.

Does this imply that $|V|\geq 2n$?

**MOTIVATION**: In the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227477/hadwiger-partitions-where-one-block-is-always-a-singleton), @bof gave excellent and short examples for graphs fulfilling conditions 1 and 2 above, each having exactly $2n$ vertices. It's not hard to find other examples with at least this number of vertices. So now, it's open season for smaller examples -- if they exist!

Comment: can you give an example of such a graph with $|V|\ge 2n$?

Comment: Yes, 2 copies of $K_n$, see http://mathoverflow.net/a/227483/8628

Comment: The singleton block condition seems redundant as for at most 2n-1 vertices you can just apply the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octahedron$                            .$

Comment: Can you elaborate? I suppose you found a counterexample..

Comment: Yes, an octahedron seems to serve as a counterexample.

Comment: Please explain what an octahedron is and why it is a counterexample, Ilya or domotorp, so I can accept the answer and award the bounty.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OctahedralGraph.html